# use React.createElement inside nested loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a nested loop and would like to append react elements to a root element in order to be passed to a different component.

Something like this:

```
let ul = React.createElement('ul', null, []);

properties.forEach((property) => {
   errors[property].error.map((e: any) => {
       React.createElement('li', null, e);
   });
});
```

question is: how do I append the 'li' to the parent 'ul' element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React discourages you from interacting with rendered content. Instead it wants you to render the right way in the first place. So I don't believe React provides a way to append children to an already rendered element.

But that third argument is the *children* of an element. So you can iterate over the properties first, and then pass the result to the `ul` rendering call.

Something like this:

```
const lis: React.ReactNode[] = []

properties.forEach((property) => {
   errors[property].error.forEach((e: any) => {
       lis.push(React.createElement('li', null, e));
   });
});

const ul = React.createElement('ul', null, lis);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let ul = React.createElement('ul', null, properties.map((property) => (
   errors[property].error.map((e: any) => {
      return React.createElement('li', null, e);
   })
)));
```